# BigQuery ML - Identifier 'dataset' starts with invalid character

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a new ML model in BigQuery UI. I am using the dataset '1234' in the project 'project_id' and creating the model 'MLtest'.

However I am presented with the following error:

```
Identifier '1234' starts with invalid character '1'
```

Code in standard SQL:

```
CREATE MODEL `project_id.1234.MLtest`
Options (model_type='linear_reg'
, labels = ['label']) AS

SELECT * FROM `project_id.1234.ga_sessions_X`
```

The query works as intended without the first three lines of code.

I have tried to use other datasets '2345' , '3456' but the error still occurs with the invalid character being '2' and '3' instead.

Both formats for creating models: 
    **'dataset.model_name'** and **'project_id.dataset.model_name'** presents the same error.

I've tried to create previous successful models again with  a new name. But the error still occurs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug; I submitted [an issue on BigQuery's public issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118128400) on your behalf. In the meantime, you need to create a dataset that doesn't start with a number in order to use the `CREATE MODEL` statement.

Comment: Thank you Elliott for submitting the bug, it has now been resolved.